# Autofill email input box in php

Tags: php, html, email, autofill

i want to send certain emails to my clients and a link is provided in those emails(something like a activation email to active your account), when users click on that link they are directed to a page on my website , that page has a email input box.

I want that when they click on that link and get redirected to my site the input field should be automatically filled with email from where user has clicked the link.(note the user need not be signed in on my site)

Any way i can do this , im using PHP

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well you can pass some data in URL e.g Correspodant ID and then look up the database which ID to be AUTOFilled...

Alternatively you can merge Email id in URL and put that in email and then when user HIT that URL the correspondant email ID will be part of the URL as query string that you can read and put in textbox.

```
let's use your example 
http://www.example.com/example.php?id=USEREMAIL

you could access the value of the variable id in the $_GET array like so

echo $_GET['USEREMAIL'];

this would output "UserEmail". It is common to pull these into a local variable such as

$myid = $_GET['USEREMAIL'];

this would be the some syntax for any var in your url, take this example

http://www.example.com/example.php?AutoFillEmail=developerjigar@gmail.com&start=40&section=mysupercat

$myid = $_GET['AutoFillEmail']; 
$start = $_GET['start']; 
$section = $_GET['section'];
```

Hope you understand

Comment: buddy but i m sending the links to bulk users , for looping and appending the email to each link would not be considered a good practice ideally. Thanks anyways appreciate the help

Comment: and idea is shown for storing in the db and use Correspodant in URL would be best practise.

Comment: but i dont want to touch the databse which automatically populating the input email box

Comment: in that case how would you approach??? you can do it with URL only because email client can not POST info to PHP server right? URL is the only way out and you can send Either all the emails or CommunicationID and trip DB... let us know if there is any other way you find